# Crontab to reload PM2 cluster processes

Tags: pm2

I'm around this issue for one day with no effective results. Imagine I want to reload (zero downtime, thus not restart) a PM2 cluster process every hour with `crontab`.

The PM2 app is this one, which I start with `sudo pm2 start app.json` (btw, I think it's not relevant, but I'm using pm2 as sudo, I can't recall why)

```json
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"        : "autocosts.prod",
    "script"      : "bin/server.js",
    "cwd"         : "/var/www/autocosts.prod/",
    "node_args"   : "--use_strict",
    "args"        : "-r prod --print --pdf --social --googleCaptcha --googleAnalytics --database",
    "exec_mode"   : "cluster",
    "instances"   : 4,
    "wait_ready"  : true,
    "listen_timeout" : 50000,
    "watch"       : false,
    "exp_backoff_restart_delay" : 200,
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "production"
    },
    "log_date_format": "DD-MM-YYYY"
  }]
}
```

My crontab line is

```
# reload every hour
0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/pm2 reload /var/www/autocosts.prod/app.json > /var/log/pm2/app.cron.log 2>&1
```

But on that log file I get an error

```
[PM2] Applying action reloadProcessId on app [autocosts.prod](ids: [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ])
[PM2][ERROR] Process 0 not found
Process 0 not found
```

It seems PM2 can't detect the id numbers of the cluster.

How to have crontabs to reload (zero downtime) a PM2 cluster process?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, was indeed due to the fact that I was using pm2 as sudo and crontab in sudo mode has no access to a series of environments.

Change owner of PM2 to yourself (do `which pm2` to find the full path of the executable), such that you can use it without sudo. Do the same for `~/.pm2`.